# How do i include OpenCL kernels as resources in XCode?

Tags: xcode, opencl

In this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/XCodeHelloWorld/XCodeHelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH10-SW2), for figure 1-1 at the Group HelloWorld, there are 2 files, one is the `.c` file and the other is the `.cl` file which is the kernel file. However I am not sure on how to create `.cl` file. May I know where do I need to look in order to locate the `.cl` file to be added for my HelloWorld group?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the *HelloWorld* group, then select *New File…*, choose *Other/Empty* and enter a filename with the *.cl* extension. Xcode will recognize the extension and automatically compile the file and create the appropriate *.cl.h* header on build.